# should i store page data in json?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, content-management-system

i am writing a cms system in php 5.3 on top codeigniter. The contents of the data, i have determined, it will very in size and form and i was wondering if storing the data in JSON format in MySQL would be a good choice. I need to be able to store data in a structured way, but the way it is structured, the number of subtitles will very, the use of lists, tables, or other elements may be needed at times.

I want to create a lib of tools in the end for creating different types of sites, have the lib built very modular so that u can strip it down to the minimum sized footprint for each site.

Is JSON a the right choice or would it be to processor intensive?

Comment: JSON is a good, reasonably compact way to represent arbitrarily structured data for storage or transmission.  It cannot be readily searched/queried, however, so any queries of the DB should use key fields separate from the JSON data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON in MySQL?  No, don't do that.

Arrays and structures are readily built from the result of a SQL query, and readily converted to JSON format ([json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) when needed which is not much, except when creating JavaScript.

Going the other direction is straightforward too:  convert JSON to PHP arrays/hashtables  ([json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) and use that to create a SQL query to update or insert into a set of tables.

Comment: Personally, I'd use serialize over json.